# Adding data to a nested JSON object with children based on an array - Javascript/REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, function, nested

Hello stackoverflow community! I've been creating my own fullstack application for a while now, on the NEXTjs framework. This is going pretty well!! Unfortunately, I got stuck on a JSON import object for a treeview component. The treeview component must be populated using a specific nested structure, along with which treeview item should be selected on an initial render.

I managed to get the correct JSON object from the database, using a sql recursive tree function.

```
const jsonObject = 

{
    "id": "bfa3fdf8-4672-404e-baf5-0f9098a5705b",
    "label": "main category 1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
            "label": "sub category 1.1",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "3f5e5cc7-f8b2-4d75-89e1-841c66d863e6",
            "label": "sub category 1.2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "903a727f-d94d-44ff-b2f6-a985fd167343",
                    "label": "sub category 1.2.1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
                    "label": "sub category 1.2.2",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that this object, with categories needs to be updated with a 'checked: "true"' or 'checked: "false"' key value pair based on the existence in the referenceSelectedCategories array. And I don't know how to do this; maintaining the structure and object as needed.

```
const desiredOutputJsonObject = 

{
    "id": "bfa3fdf8-4672-404e-baf5-0f9098a5705b",
    "label": "main category 1",
**  "checked": "false",**
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
            "label": "sub category 1.1",
**          "checked": "true",**
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "3f5e5cc7-f8b2-4d75-89e1-841c66d863e6",
            "label": "sub category 1.2",
**          "checked": "false",**
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "903a727f-d94d-44ff-b2f6-a985fd167343",
                    "label": "sub category 1.2.1",
**                  "checked": "false",**                    
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
                    "label": "sub category 1.2.2",
**                  "checked": "true",**   
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
const referenceSelectedCategories = 
[
    {
        "categoryId": "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
        "productId": "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
        "Id": "f82b0f63-3f39-486c-9157-5c7683b8e3b2"
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
        "productId": "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
        "Id": "b2e8681b-eec4-404d-8f87-c6314db42e30"
    }
]
```

I've read several stackoverflow questions, also searched for examples, but can't get it to work. Could someone help me out here?

Some extra information:

- Code language I'm using is REACT on NEXTjs framework;
- Treeview component could have a dept of max 5 levels;
- The structure of the JSON object doesn't change, it's exactly as presented above.
- The "id" in the JSON object corresponds to the "categoryId" in the array.
- Do you need more information? :) Just ask, I'll provide you with the extra details!

Kind Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward solution with recursive method. Done a quick test, working fine. If any issues found, please point it out.

```
    const parentObj = 
    [
        {
            "categoryId": "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
            "productId": "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
            "Id": "f82b0f63-3f39-486c-9157-5c7683b8e3b2"
        },
        {
            "categoryId": "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
            "productId": "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
            "Id": "b2e8681b-eec4-404d-8f87-c6314db42e30"
        }
    ]
    
    const existingId = parentObj.map((item)=> (item.Id))
    
    const childobj = 
    
    {
        "id": "bfa3fdf8-4672-404e-baf5-0f9098a5705b",
        "label": "main category 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
                "label": "sub category 1.1",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "3f5e5cc7-f8b2-4d75-89e1-841c66d863e6",
                "label": "sub category 1.2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "903a727f-d94d-44ff-b2f6-a985fd167343",
                        "label": "sub category 1.2.1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "f82b0f63-3f39-486c-9157-5c7683b8e3b2",
                        "label": "sub category 1.2.2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
const childObj = [childobj]
    const updateData=(obj)=> {
        if(existingId.includes(obj.id)) obj['checked'] = true; else obj['checked'] = false
    }
    
    const traverse=(childObj)=> {
        for(const obj of childObj) {
            updateData(obj);
            if(obj.children.length > 0) traverse(obj.children); 
        }
    }
    
    traverse(childObj);
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your awnser to my question. I tried the code and get the following error: TypeError: childobj[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. Could you check your code please?

Comment: @ChrisKuiper oh missed this line const childObj = [childobj], updated now

Comment: Thanks Naveen! The code works. Still getting an error, in my app. Think it has to do with me fetching the data with a useEffect instead of getServerSideProps. I'm going to move the fetching to getServerSideProps, so that the function doesn't run on an empty state.

Comment: I got it working in my application! One small remark ... "const existingId = parentObj.map((item)=> (item.Id))" should be " const existingId = parentObj.map((item)=> (item.categoryId))" but got it fixed! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can ty this logic :

```js
let desiredOutputJsonObject = {
  id: "bfa3fdf8-4672-404e-baf5-0f9098a5705b",
  label: "main category 1",
  checked: false,
  children: [
    {
      id: "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
      label: "sub category 1.1",
      checked: true,
      children: [],
    },
    {
      id: "3f5e5cc7-f8b2-4d75-89e1-841c66d863e6",
      label: "sub category 1.2",
      checked: false,
      children: [
        {
          id: "903a727f-d94d-44ff-b2f6-a985fd167343",
          label: "sub category 1.2.1",
          checked: false,
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
          label: "sub category 1.2.2",
          checked: true,
          children: [
              {
          id: "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b9",
          label: "sub category 1.2.2",
          checked: false,
          children: [],
        },
          ],
        },
          
      ],
    },
  ],
};

let referenceSelectedCategories = [
  {
    categoryId: "12e544bc-91b1-4e5d-bdbc-2163a5618305",
    productId: "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
    Id: "f82b0f63-3f39-486c-9157-5c7683b8e3b2",
  },
  {
    categoryId: "fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b4",
    productId: "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
    Id: "b2e8681b-eec4-404d-8f87-c6314db42e30",
  },
    {
    categoryId:"fb344480-8588-4ce3-9662-f8e89069e4b9",
    productId: "efed1c38-391b-4b5a-a9f1-91f3faec5f44",
    Id: "b2e8681b-eec4-404d-8f87-c6314db42e30",
  },
];

let stack = [desiredOutputJsonObject];

while (stack.length) {
  let desiredOutput = stack.pop();

  if (desiredOutput.children) {
    desiredOutput.children.forEach((node) => {
     //get node whose id == category id
      let result = referenceSelectedCategories.find(
        (obj) => obj.categoryId === node.id
      );

      //   while traversing if we get referenceSelectedCategories.categoryId ==desiredOutputJsonObject.id
      if (result) {
        node.checked = true;
      }

      // for traverse purpose
      if (node.children.length) {
        stack.push(node);
      }
    });
  }
}

console.log(desiredOutputJsonObject);
```